# Can i overwrite the identity on insert in entity framework, without db writing it over

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My column for the key

```
   this.Property(t => t.Guid).HasColumnName("Guid")
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```

And the insert.

```
         context.TrafficImages.Add(new TrafficImage { Guid = guids[i] });
                context.SaveChanges();
```

When i save, the db writes its own guid. Anyway to let me write my own guid if i define it and if not the db will create one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specify DatabaseGenerationOption.Identity EF will treat your property as one that is backed by an identity column. In this case when adding a new entity even if you set the property the value will be ignored and the one generated by your Db will be used. You can remove the HasDatabaseGeneratedOption configuration but if your database generates keys you will get an exception if EF is trying to insert a value to this column. If your database does not generate keys then you should not have the HadDatabaseGenerationOption configuration at all and you should always set key values on the client when adding new entities since the database will not create one for you. I don't think there is a mixed mode when the database creates a key for you if it is not present. You would probably have to create a stored procedure for that and map it to the Create operation. Unfortunately CodeFirst does not support mapping stored procedures to CUD operations.

Comment: Thanks. I disabled db generation and did put a Guid.NewGuid() in my constructor of the class.